# Working with Blazor Fluxor for State Manangement

Tags: blazor, fluxor

so I want to implement State Management into my blazor Server side app. My goal is to invoke an action after a selection in a grid. The Value of the Grid should then be added to the State. My Problem now is, how do I get something in the State ? The example only showed how to increment a count, but how would I get data from my application into the reducer or action ?

Answer (score 1):

When you dispatch an action, you can create parameters in the constructor for that action and pass the data you want.

```
Dispatcher.Dispatch(new FooAction(someData));
```

where `FooAction` can be something like

```
public class FooAction 
{
    public object SomeData { get; set; }

    public FooAction(object someData)
    {
        SomeData = someData;
    }
}
```

And in the reducer, you can get the data from the action

```
public override BarState Reduce(BarState state, FooAction action)
{
    // access data from BarState with state.something
    // access data from FooAction with action.something
    var someData = action.SomeData;   

    // ...do whatever you want with the data

    return new BarState();
}
```

Or, using the alternative reducer pattern

```
public static class ReducersOrAnyOtherNameItDoesntMatter
{
  [ReducerMethod]
  public static MyState Reduce(MyState state, IncrementAction action) =>
    new MyState(state.Counter += action.AmountToAddToCounter);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, your question isn't that clear, but this is a way to "get data from my application into the reducer or action".